# Hierarchical XML to Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing, hierarchy

I'm trying to convert data streaming from a medical device into a usable table.  The device spits out XML-formatted text via an RS-232 port, which I've captured using a software called ComCap4 from Magenta Systems.  I've been able to convert the one row per line of text into an XML object, but am getting turned around by the XML syntax in SQL Server.

Here's an example of the XML:

```
<sample>
  <instrinfo>
    <p>
      <n>SNO</n>
      <v>179</v>
    </p>
  </instrinfo>
  <smpinfo>
    <p>
      <n>ID</n>
      <v>26551.0</v>
    </p>
  </smpinfo>
  <smpresults>
    <p>
      <n>WBC</n>
      <v>8.4</v>
      <l>3.5</l>
      <h>10.0</h>
    </p>
  </smpresults>
</sample>
<sample>
  <instrinfo>
    <p>
      <n>SNO</n>
      <v>179</v>
    </p>
  </instrinfo>
  <smpinfo>
    <p>
      <n>ID</n>
      <v>26552.0</v>
    </p>
  </smpinfo>
  <smpresults>
    <p>
      <n>WBC</n>
      <v>6.1</v>
      <l>3.5</l>
      <h>10.0</h>
    </p>
  </smpresults>
</sample>
```

I'd like to convert this XML into a table that looks like:

```
InstrumentSNO  SampleID  WBCVal  WBCLow  WBCHigh
-------------  --------  ------  ------  -------
179            26551.0   8.4     3.5     10.0
179            26552.0   6.1     3.5     10.0
```

I've had very little experience parsing XML (probably obvious from this question) and the examples I've found here and elsewhere leave me more confused than ever.

Any help, links, or suggestions in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<sample>
  <instrinfo>
    <p>
      <n>SNO</n>
      <v>179</v>
    </p>
  </instrinfo>
  <smpinfo>
    <p>
      <n>ID</n>
      <v>26551.0</v>
    </p>
  </smpinfo>
  <smpresults>
    <p>
      <n>WBC</n>
      <v>8.4</v>
      <l>3.5</l>
      <h>10.0</h>
    </p>
  </smpresults>
</sample>
<sample>
  <instrinfo>
    <p>
      <n>SNO</n>
      <v>179</v>
    </p>
  </instrinfo>
  <smpinfo>
    <p>
      <n>ID</n>
      <v>26552.0</v>
    </p>
  </smpinfo>
  <smpresults>
    <p>
      <n>WBC</n>
      <v>6.1</v>
      <l>3.5</l>
      <h>10.0</h>
    </p>
  </smpresults>
</sample>';
```

--Here is the query

```
SELECT s.value('(instrinfo/p/v)[1]','int') AS InstrumentSNO
      ,s.value('(smpinfo/p/v)[1]','decimal(10,1)') AS SampleID
      ,s.value('(smpresults/p/v)[1]','decimal(10,1)') AS WBCVal
      ,s.value('(smpresults/p/l)[1]','decimal(10,1)') AS WBCLow
      ,s.value('(smpresults/p/h)[1]','decimal(10,1)') AS WBCHigh
FROM @xml.nodes('/sample') AS A(s)
```

The result

```
InstrumentSNO   SampleID    WBCVal  WBCLow  WBCHigh
179             26551.0     8.4     3.5     10.0
179             26552.0     6.1     3.5     10.0
```

### Short explanation

Your XML contains - obviously - sets of `sample` element. With `CROSS APPLY .nodes('/sample')` we can address them one by one.

Although there are nested elements, all of them seem to be 1:1 named elements, so we can just pick them by their names with a relativ path down from the `sample`-node.

Comment: Thanks for the quick, accurate response!  Works perfectly.